# How to create different relationships in neo4j using py2neo reading csv files?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I would like to read in a csv file where the first two columns have node names, and the third column has the node relationship.  Currently I use this in py2neo:

query2 = """

USING PERIODIC COMMIT

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data.csv" AS line

MERGE (topic:Topic {name: line.Topic})

MERGE (result:Result {name: line.Result})

CREATE UNIQUE (topic)-[:DISCUSSES]->(result)

"""

## How can I use the third column in the csv file to set the relationship, instead of having all relationships set as "DISCUSSES"?

I tried this, but it does not have a UNIQUE option:

query1 = """

USING PERIODIC COMMIT

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data.csv" AS line

MERGE (topic:Topic {name: line.Topic})

MERGE (result:Result {name: line.Result})

MERGE (relation:Relation {name: line.Relation})

WITH topic,result,line

CALL apoc.merge.relationship(topic, line.Relation, {}, {}, result) YIELD rel as rel1

RETURN topic,result

"""

Comment: The latest neo4j versions no longer support `CREATE UNIQUE`. You should use [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) instead.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question: Is there a way to set the relationships using a column in the csv file?

Comment: Thank you, yes, I read it and tried it on my problem set.  APOC does not seem to have a UNIQUE option, which I need, as shown in the code above.

Comment: OK, see my answer. You were actually close to having a good query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your second query is almost correct (except that it has an extraneous `MERGE` clause). Here is the corrected query:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data.csv" AS line
MERGE (topic:Topic {name: line.Topic})
MERGE (result:Result {name: line.Result})
WITH topic, result, line
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(topic, line.Relation, {}, {}, result) YIELD rel
RETURN topic, result
```

The `apoc.merge.relationship` call is equivalent to doing a `MERGE` to create the relationship (with a dynamic label) if it does not already exist.